# Parent View toggles Partial Views - on click triggers multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have Parent View and 2 Partial Views. I have buttons on each partial view that is registered for an on click event on the parent page. They do ajax calls to get their respective partial view.

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetEmployee(int id)
        {
            HumanResourcesManager man = new HumanResourcesManager();
            var emp = man.GetEmployee(id);
            EmployeeModel empModel = new EmployeeModel(emp);
            return PartialView("_EmployeeDetails", empModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetEmployeeForEdit(int id)
        {
            HumanResourcesManager man = new HumanResourcesManager();
            var emp = man.GetEmployee(id);
            ViewBag.States = man.GetStates();
            EmployeeModel empModel = new EmployeeModel(emp);
            return PartialView("_EmployeeEdit", empModel);
        }
```

**Parent View**

```
  @model HumanResources.Web.Models.EmployeeModel
  <p>
     Selected Employee: @Html.TextBox("EmployeeSearch")
   </p>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#EmployeeSearch").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@(Url.Action("FindEmployee", "Employee"))",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.DisplayName, value: item.DisplayName, id: item.Id };
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
                    GetEmployeeDetails(ui.item.id);
                }
            }
        });



    function GetEmployeeDetails(id) {

        $("partialView").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(Url.Action("GetEmployee", "Employee"))",
            data: { id: id },
            success:function(result)
            {
                $("#partialView").html(result);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });

        @*$(document).on('click', "#empEdit", function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@(Url.Action("GetEmployeeForEdit", "Employee"))",
                data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)),
                success:function(result)
                {
                    $("#partialView").html(result);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            })
        });*@

        $(document).on('click', "#empEdit", function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@(Url.Action("GetEmployeeForEdit", "Employee"))",
                data: {id: $("#editEmployeeId").val()},
            success:function(result)
            {
                $("#partialView").html(result);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        })
    });

        $(document).on('click', "#empEditCancel", function(){
            GetEmployeeDetails($("#editEmployeeId").val());
        });

}
</script>

<div id="partialView">
</div>
```

**Partial View - Details**
The details is intended to display details and an edit button. The JavaScript I have in the Parent View.

```
@model HumanResources.Web.Models.EmployeeModel
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}


    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Employee.Id, new { id = "editEmployeeId" })

    @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.Employee.FirstName)

    <input id="empEdit" type="button" value="Edit"/>
```

**Partial View - Edit**
The Edit View displays the same values as the details partial view, but as editable fields.

```
    @model HumanResources.Web.Models.EmployeeModel 
 @{
     Layout = null; 
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Employee")) {

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Employee.Id, new { Id = "editEmployeeId" })

<div class="container">

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />

    <input id="empEditCancel" type="button" value="Cancel"/>
</div> 
}
```

**My Issue**

Editing and cancelling (toggling between the two partial views) once works fine. Editing and cancelling more than once it seems that the functions for the on click are called increasingly number of times by a factor of 2. Causing the alerts to be called multiple times.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your `GetEmployeeDetails()` script?

Comment: Sorry I left that out. It's basically just another function to do another ajax call that will provide the partial view for the details.

Comment: what is the `$("partialView")` in `GetEmployeeDetails`? i dont think it will find any and empty it, how the html look like for the view and partial view button?

Comment: It's just an empty div. I've updated the question to indicate this.

Comment: can't see any issue with your script, although `$("partialView").empty();` might had issue where it miss `#`, still there is multiple possible why it build up, possible due to multiple same js reference in page

Comment: Do you have any script in the partials?

Comment: @StephenMuecke
Nope. I was under the impression that best practice is to not put any javascript in the partial views. Everything works too, but I just noticed one of my breakpoints kept hitting an increasing number of times.

Comment: This code looks fine. it should work fine. I am hoping that you are returning a partial view result from those action methods.

Comment: Yes, scripts should not in in partials (just trying to rule out possible causes). The code you have shown works fine, so there is something else you have not shown us causing the issue.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've updated with complete details. To be clear, everything works. The first time I click, it hits the controller methods once and returns the partial view. The second time, it will call the controller methods twice. Then four times, Then 8.